# Azure Key Vault - Deletion of Key in PowerShell Script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am trying to run this statement in a PowerShell script. The script is run during the release in VSTS.

I am following Microsoft's suggestion on how to delete keys from a Key Vault in Azure.

Example how to remove a specific key.

```
Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'ContosoKeyVault' -Name 'ContosoFirstKey' -Force
```

However, I get the following error afterwards.

> PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is
>   not available.

I have read that it is because I cannot have interactions with PowerShell in this case, such as confirming the deletion ofthe Key on a pop up window.

I tried then the -Force command on the deletion statement, without success.

Can anyone explain / show how to get past this?

Comment: try the same command interactive and observe the prompt and fix it. also there should be no `:` after force

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'ContosoKeyVault' -Name 'ContosoFirstKey' -Force -Confirm:$False
```